# LaTeX3 - Difference between fatal and critical errors

Tags: errors, latex3, message

Can someone explain concretely the difference between fatal and critical errors?

The `interface3` documentation just says :

> ***• fatal, ending the TEX run;***
>
> ***• critical, ending the file being input;***

*PS: in Python and JAVA, fatal and critical are synonyms.*

Comment: A TeX run can load several files. If I take the explanation literally, a critical error should only terminate the loading of the current file, while a fatal error should terminate the entire TeX run. So with `… \input{foo.tex} … \bar` a critical error in `foo.tex` will still execute `\bar` but a fatal error wouldn't. See also the description of `\msg_fatal:…` and `\msg_critical:…`.

Comment: I've read the documentation, but I still can't think of a context in which the difference in usage might be useful.

Comment: you might for exmple want to give an error on a luatex-specific package, and recover by (just) skiping the package

Comment: Degraded but not blocking use is a good example. I keep it in mind.